# How can this folder be significantly larger on disk than the sum of its files?

Tags: hard-drive, filesystem, apfs

I'm using an APFS-formatted drive under macOS 10.14, and I have found that various folders on my hard drive read like this when I use Get Info on them:

2,959,512 bytes (4.1 MB on disk) for 19 items

...and I'm trying to figure out why they would take so much more space on disk than the information they contain. Across the whole HD I think there may be a total of 4-5GB of unexplainable disk usage.

If anyone is interested in examining the specific folder, I've taken the uncommon step of uploading it here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/i4uwuky1dp9qkf1/Player.zip?dl=1 . When I unzip it, the resulting folder gives me the same readout in Get Info as the original folder, so you should be able to see what I'm seeing.

If you examine these files, please note that all but one (the application) contain no data in their data forks, only in their resource forks. I don't believe that is relevant to the curious amount of space taken up on disk, but maybe it is. There's also a small amount of metainformation in the directory (the 19th file) which does not explain the space being taken up.

= = = = = = =

To those who are thinking it's the HD's block size: my block size is 4KiB (both device and allocation size) according to diskutil, so clearly a folder with 19 items that contain 2.96MB would not take up 4.1MB due to block size inefficiency. I do see that each file counts as 2 files internally due to the two forks in each, but at most that should add another 72KiB to the storage on disk, not 1.1MB.

I will say that for some reason the allocation of space on disk for each file does not seem to be in multiples of 4KiB like I usually see for files on my hard drive. For instance the file "Acircle" has about 27KB of data but occupies 29KB on disk; shouldn't that be 28KB? *[Edit: This is explained by @klanomath in the comment below.]* Nevertheless, the sum of the unusual on-disk sizes of these files is still 3.0MB, not 4.1MB. And I see no invisible files in the directory that could be hiding the extra 1.1MB. Can anyone solve this puzzle?

Comment: Please add your file system! BTW the 26.934 Byte Acircle file occupies 7x4096 Byte = 28672 Byte = ~29 KB ([SI Units metric prefixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units#Prefixes)) (but 28 KiB)

Comment: @klanomath Oops, I must be losing my mind after staring at this problem for so long!  I have added my file system and also my macOS version.  I see what you mean re: KiB vs. KB for Acircle, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: The app (inside of a folder) is the culprit (check this by moving it to a new folder). The folder has a size of 2.154/3.3 MB and the app in the folder 2.154/2.2 MB. The rest of the files in the other folder occupy a reasonable size: 810/844 KB.

Comment: Yes, I see.  It's still a mystery as to why, though. I find it interesting that the resource fork of the application is 1.1MB.  It's almost as if it's being counted twice by Finder.  Might be a coincidence, though, because other folders that have the same problem cannot be explained in the same way.  For instance, see this folder of header files from an old open-source project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/n8r72hbn4wf9del/Headers.zip?dl=1 .  When expanded, there's 28KB of data in 9 .h files, but they require 123KB in disk space. (I'm using small folders as examples since they're easier to study.)

Comment: This is the secret life of PowerPC PEF executables and their header files and the late revenge on Apple software and hardware engineers moving away from PPC/HFS to Intel/APFS. The silent highwaymen occupy all the free space saved by modern file system compression in the newer macOS(s).

Comment: Ha, tell me about it. Interestingly, if you tell Finder via AppleScript to give the physical size ("size on disk") for these folders, you get the theoretically correct answer that comes from allocating 4KiB blocks for each resource/data fork. I wrote a script to retrieve these logical and physical sizes via AppleScript and a second script to calculate the "correct" size based on the actual data in each fork, and the scripts return identical results. It's only the Get Info window that returns nonsensical results for the "on disk" size.

Comment: *Re: When expanded, there's 28KB of data in 9 .h files* **Not true**: The 28 KB are 1 x file with 3 allocblocks, 1 x file 2 and 7 x files with 1 **+** 9 x 1 allocblock resource fork = 21 x 4096. So you are probably right that the resource fork(s) is (are) counted twice on APFS: 12 x 1 data + 9 x res + 9 x res = 30 x 4096=122880. On HFS+ it's 21 x 4096=86016 (Byte).

Comment: Hmm, no It's even more "nonsensical": If you compare the Headers and the Player folder it appears to be like this: the lower number of fork-allocblocks (either data **or** resource fork) are counted twice. The Header folder's files occupy 9 res fork allocblocks and 12 data fork allocblocks and the diff (APFS vs. HFS+) is 9 allocblocks (30-21). The Player folder's files occupy ~500 res fork allocblocks and 254 data fork allocblock and the diff (APFS vs. HFS+) is 254 blocks (~1000-~754).

Comment: I think you're right! I added some code to my Bash script to predict what Finder is going to give as the "on disk" size by double-adding the size of whichever fork total is smaller, and it works for these two directories as well as several others that show the same issue. I should try this in my 10.15 test partition to see if Apple has fixed the bug (seems unlikely). Thanks for helping me work on this. I think the multi-GB discrepancy I'm seeing on my HD is not caused by this, but this helps narrow it down. If you want to write this up as an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: I tested it in 10.11 (HFS+) and 10.13/10.15 (both APFS). The Finder folder info is still wrong in 10.15. I find it hard to write an answer without knowing the reason (simply writing: "It's a bug" won't be sufficient).

Comment: I see; well, you're much more experienced on SE than I am.  I figured that "It's not really that large, the displayed size is an APFS-related bug" would be acceptable :-)  Thanks again for your help.